# Will SwiftSoup be able to parse this correctly?

Tags: swift, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For better context, the url I am scraping/parsing is: https://www.dreamflows.com/xlist-ca.php

[image]

I'm using SwiftSoup to parse HTML but from the documentation, I'm not sure if it's possible. The html has a bunch of these rows and the text I need is unfortunately not in an element (not even a p tag). It's always following an img tag.

Specifically,

1. ```
       '<img src="./Dreamflows California Cross-Listing_files/pixelshim.gif" width="12" border="0">'
   ```
2. Name of river section
3. ```
       &nbsp;
   ```

Note that there is a similar scenario where there is

1. ```
       <a href="https://www.dreamflows.com/xlist-ca.php#Special_Symbols"><img src="./Dreamflows California Cross-Listing_files/querySym.gif" border="0"></a>
   ```
2. Name of a river section
3. ```
        &nbsp;
   ```

**I don't want these.**

**So in my example, only North Fork Smith River - Low Divide Rd to Gasquet (14.6 miles, III to V-, H&S p69) should be parsed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following selector to identify the image `img[src$="pixelshim.gif"]` and from there pick the text.

*based on your tags this example uses beautifulsoup (python) just for demonstration*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(
            requests.get('https://www.dreamflows.com/xlist-ca.php').text
)

for e in soup.select('img[src$="pixelshim.gif"]'):
    print(e.next)
```

Output

```
North Fork Smith River - Low Divide Rd to Gasquet (14.6 miles, III to V-, H&S p69)  
Middle Fork Smith River - Siskiyou Gorge (0.8 mile, IV+ to V, AWetState)  
Middle Fork Smith River - Patrick Creek Run (8.4 miles, III+ to IV, H&S p71)  
North Fork Smith River - Low Divide Rd to Gasquet (14.6 miles, III to V-, H&S p69)  
Middle Fork Smith River - Patrick Creek Run (8.4 miles, III+ to IV, H&S p71)  
Smith River - Gasquet Run (4.5 miles, II+ to III, Creekin')  
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully SwiftSoup should be able to do the same.